# Should I put different NavMesh's in different classes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

So I have these three classes for a game I'm making. Infection Controller, then 2 child classes, InfectedClass and BloaterClass. This is in the InfectionController:

```
void UpdateTarget()
{
    GameObject[] Humans = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(humanTag);
    GameObject[] Vaccines = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(vaccineTag);
    GameObject[] HV = Humans.Concat(Vaccines).ToArray();

    float shortestDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
    GameObject nearestHuman = null;
    Vector3 currentPosition = this.transform.position;

    foreach (GameObject huvacs in HV)
    {
        Vector3 directionToTarget = huvacs.transform.position - currentPosition;

        float distanceToTarget = directionToTarget.sqrMagnitude;
        if (distanceToTarget < shortestDistance)
        {
            shortestDistance = distanceToTarget;
            nearestHuman = huvacs;
        }
        else
        {
            targetHuman = null;
        }
    }

    if (nearestHuman != null && shortestDistance <= range)
    {
        targetHuman = nearestHuman.transform;
        infectionAgent.SetDestination(targetHuman.transform.position);
    }
}
```

So both the Infected and Bloater share this script but I want them to have different speeds. I ran into the issue where if I change the speed of the NavMeshAgent in my Start() function, I'm changing the speed of all the infection units to the same thing.

So... should I just put this movement method in the subclasses? Or is there a way to change the speed based on the subclass inside of the parent class?

Answer (score 1):

> So... should I just put this movement method in the subclasses?

Is it going to be the exact same code? Then no. Never copy and paste the same code to multiple places.

> If I change the speed of the NavMeshAgent in my Start() function, I'm changing the speed of all the infection units to the same thing [...] Is there a way to change the speed based on the subclass inside of the parent class?

You haven't shown your `Start()` method, but you should set the speed value from your sub-classes, not the parent class. Note that the Unity magic names (like `Start`) don't inherit well. You can create your own method (that's called from `Start()`) and is marked `virtual` allowing your subclasses to override it and get the behavior you want.